# WinForm Grid: How to hide the scrollbar thumb

Tags: .net, winforms

I'd like to write a WinForm program to display large files in a DataGridView control. In the case where the file is a very large CSV file, I'd like to hide the thumb of the scrollbar because the number of rows in the file will not be known until the entire file is parsed.

How can I hide the thumb bar?

About 13 years ago I used Spread VBX for a similar type of program. It supported virtual mode and had a property to hide the thumb bar. I don't mind open source, but I'm hoping not to have to purchase a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the scrollbars until you finish processing the file using:

```
DataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
```

And when you finish display them again:

```
DataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not try to hide the scroll bars, only the thumb, the rectangular shape within the scroll bar that indicates the current relative position within the list that a user can drag to randomly position into the file. The user should be allowed to scroll, but not jump to a random position in a file of unknown length